# What is the best toolset for making an application that includes a built-in web server?

Tags: php, web-applications, embedded-linux, embeddedwebserver

I want to create an application where the GUI is accessed using a web browser.  That way, the program can be used either locally or remotely.  I want to be able to compile both PC (using cygwin or mingw) and Linux versions of the program.  What is a good framework to accomplish this?

I will need the following features:

web server (preferably written in C)

PHP (including SQLite capability)

small system resources (able to compile it to run in an embedded system with 32MB ram)

The user interface aspects of the program will be written in HTML/PHP/JavaScript and access to a special I/O device will be written in C.  The data from the I/O subsystem will be stored into a SQLite database so that the Web based user interface can access the data from PHP.

So far, mongoose looks like a candidate for this project.  Does anyone have any experience with this? What other alternatives exist?

Comment: Here is a list of possible candidates for this project: [http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/]  [http://sites.google.com/site/snorkelembedded]  
[http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/]  
[http://eclipse.org/jetty/] 
[http://appwebserver.org/] 
[http://qt.nokia.com/products] 
[http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/] 

Anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 3):

[hiphop-php](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) developed by facebook, translates your codes for c and compiles with apache + apache and php modules that you choosed in a unique and faster executable file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  hiphop-php may be usefull for me for this project, however, I want to keep most of the application as PHP (thus allowing easy changes to the application without having to compile anything).  I will use C for the low level hardware communications.

<p>Here is something that may fit the bill: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt </p>